# Windows default programs: unable to make changes

Tags: windows

I am administrator of this machine. UAC is completely disabled. I want to clear the defaults for Firefox, but am unable to do that because the check boxes aren't clickable.

I can uninstall Firefox but I'm just curious about this.

Anyone has any clues?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove firefox from the given extensions from here you can only det firefox to those extension from here. To clear firefox defaults (to remove firefox from these extension) go to

```
Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Default Programs > Set Associations
```

(Second Option **Associate a file type or protocol with a program**)
and sort by current defaults then find the entries by firefox and you can change from here.

Once you change the entries for firefox the check boxes will be active in firefox option that you have shown in Image. I have tested and It's working.